# Cannot format/detect external HDD

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an external hard disk that I can't access. I tried using HDDGurus low-level format on windows and it wouldn't see. I couldn't see it using `diskpart` in windows. It won't appear through `fdisk` on ubuntu. However, if I input `lsusb` without it plugged in I get

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1837 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57fa Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c537 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and with it plugged in I get

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1837 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57fa Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c537 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so the device `Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bc2:ab28 Seagate RSS LLC` can be seen by my computer however I don't know how to go about trying to format it or change it to GPT/MBR or anything. Also, I compared `ls /dev` with and without the drive plugged in and the only difference was `sg1` appearing when the drive was plugged in, I have no idea what to even try doing with that bit of info though. `lsblk` returns

```
loop0                 7:0    0  14.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/254
loop1                 7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop2                 7:2    0  35.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop3                 7:3    0   2.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop4                 7:4    0  14.5M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop5                 7:5    0    13M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop6                 7:6    0 612.9M  1 loop  /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/133
loop7                 7:7    0     8M  1 loop  /snap/evince/60
loop8                 7:8    0   7.5M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/58
loop9                 7:9    0    57M  1 loop  /snap/powershell/21
loop10                7:10   0  89.3M  1 loop  /snap/core/6673
loop11                7:11   0  1008K  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop12                7:12   0 517.4M  1 loop  /snap/intellij-idea-community/137
loop13                7:13   0  34.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop14                7:14   0     4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop15                7:15   0     4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop16                7:16   0  53.7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/782
loop17                7:17   0  14.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/206
loop18                7:18   0 550.4M  1 loop  /snap/intellij-idea-educational/4
loop19                7:19   0   3.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop20                7:20   0  86.9M  1 loop  /snap/core/4917
loop21                7:21   0 140.9M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop22                7:22   0 143.5M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
loop23                7:23   0   3.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
loop24                7:24   0 202.3M  1 loop  /snap/vlc/770
loop25                7:25   0  1008K  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop26                7:26   0   3.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
loop27                7:27   0  53.7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/941
sda                   8:0    0   4.6T  0 disk  
sr0                  11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
nvme0n1             259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 237.3G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:0    0 237.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root
    │               253:1    0 236.3G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
                    253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it get detected by `lsblk` ?

Comment: the return for `lsblk` is too long for a comment ill add it to my post

Comment: Is your external hdd showed as `sda` drive, and have capacity of 5TB ? `sda                   8:0    0   4.6T  0 disk `

Comment: That's my disk yup.

Comment: Any idea about what to do now? Really glad I can at least see it, gives me hope I'll be able to revive it and won't lose my 5TB hard drive forever. I tried `mount /dev/sda /mnt` but it just stalled and never completed the command.

Comment: You say it's fine to format it, so is there possibility to use [dban](https://dban.org/) to do such thing ?

Comment: Not a bad idea. although I tried to do that to fix an issue I was having with an m.2 drive and discovered that DBAN does not work right on my pc. I did find some process you can do while making the bootable media that might fix it but I never got around to doing it. is there a distro you know of off hand that has DBAN included?